# How do I send the a String to AppDelegate in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate

I've create a class 'Datetool' inherit from NSObject to record the date when the application was launched. But I need to show the startTime string in the AppDelegate.

I tried to use the Block to send the string with a variable declared in 'AppDelegate.h', however, I couldn't get it in Datetool's method `initialize`.

Datetool.m

```
static NSString *startTime2;

+(void)initialize
{

   if (self == [DateTool self])
   { 
       NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
       [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
       [formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
       startTime2 = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    }
}
```

Comment: you can access to the appDelegate instance via [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate

Comment: Why don't you just call a function in AppDelegate when the app starts and populate a local variable?

Comment: Yes, I did. Then I couldn't get the block in appdelegate via  [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.dateToolBlock .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you provide a delegate protocol in your DateTool which is implemented by your AppDelegate. For example (not tested):

DateTool.h:

```
/** The delegate protocol of DateTool. */

@protocol DateToolDelegate <NSObject>

/** The start date was set. */
- (void)startDateSet:(NSDate)startDate;

@end

@interface DateTool : NSObject

/** The delegate of DateTool. */
@property (weak) id<DateToolDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

DateTool.m:

```
+(void)initialize
{

   if (self == [DateTool self])
   { 
       NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
       [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
       [formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
       startTime2 = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
       if ([_delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(DateToolDelegate)]) {
           [_delegate startDateSet:startTime2];
       }
    }
}
```

In AppDelegate.h you need to add the protocol:

```
#import "DateTool.h"
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <DateToolDelegate>
```

In your AppDelegate.m you need to register itself as delegate:

```
...    
dateTool.delegate = self;
...
```

and implement the protocol:

```
- (void)startDateSet:(NSDate)startDate
{
// Do something with startDate
}
```

Hope that helps.

PS: Why is initialize a class method? I'd suggest to instantiate an object.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply call a function in the AppDelegate when the app starts.(warning I have not tried compiling this).

```
- (NSString*)getStartDate {

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
    [formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    return [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
}
```

Comment: thanks. The real demand is to get the date from the other class when it called the method `initialize`.

Comment: Then use a delegate protocol as suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

You can get at your AppDelegate from anywhere by using the UIApplication's singleton method: `[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate`
Just cast it as your custom class to access specific methods: `(AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate`

That said, I don't think that's the right approach to take here. Your Datetool is a utility class and shouldn't be reliant on references to the AppDelegate, which makes for very tightly coupled code. Instead, Datetool should be able to be called from the AppDelegate and return the desired value. Since you're already using a class method, it doesn't seem like Datetool needs an instance at all. You can scrap storing the static value and just return what you need:

```
+ (NSString*)startTime
{ 
   NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
   [formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
   return [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
}
```

Now you're pulling a value from the tool rather than trying to push it onto the AppDelegate, which makes it reusable for other purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be a bad idea to import the class definition to AppDelegate.h and instantiate the object within AppDelegate?

Comment: It's not clear from the question, but I think the OP is probably having compiler errors as it doesn't know what `dateToolBlock` is.  He needs to import `AppDelegate.h` and probably cast `[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate` to `(AppDelegate *)`.